Windows 11 23H2 - How do I remove the "Account Manager" popup from the Start menu?
Recently, Microsoft deployed a non-requested or useful feature:

Windows edition:

Before the latest update this is what it used to show:

I cannot find any documentation how to remove it. Does anyone know how to remove it?

What is the feature? 23H2 or 24H2? The screenshot seems to be from Settings-> Account which has been around since 2015. The fact the screenshot is cropped not to include other information makes it more confusing. I am extremely confused by this question.

Your screenshot doesn't show much context. How do you bring up this panel? How do you dismiss it? Where is it in relation to other things in the UI? "Useless" is not really a problem, per se. A quick panel for access to my account settings has SOME benefit to me, for instance. Have you checked Windows Settings yet? Please EDIT your question to make the problem more clear, and to more carefully indicate what you have tried so far.

just don't click on your username in the start menu ... crisis averted

This is from the Start Menu @Ramhound

Hi @music2myear, I expanded it.

This isn’t a new feature. It’s been around in some capacity since probably Windows 7. Only difference is the inclusion of information about your Microsoft Account subscriptions

That's incorrect @Ramhound, before there it was Change account settings, Sign Out and Lock that was all. I shared the previous options. I added the previous screenshot also.

They moved those options but that was back with the release of Windows 11.

Again, it wasn't like that before @Ramhound and wasn't since Windows 7.

Huh, am I correct to say the primary issue is that it now takes 2 clicks to get to the Sign Out command? I can see that being annoying.

After researching more. The account manager is an optional feature of KB5040529 which was released for 24H2 not 23H2 which means more than likely your not running 23H2. This update was released on July 30 2024 and the account manager is a gradual rollout feature. Just uninstall KB5040529

@ramhound How is it an optional feature if you have to uninstall to not get it?

@NetMage - I researched that topic more than 25 days ago. What I recall is the feature was optional. If you have a question ask a question instead of using a comment to do so

I'm in the side @NetMage, I don't get how something that is "optional," I cannot disable it. If it's an optional feature, I should be able to disable it from somewhere without uninstalling it since sooner or later it would not be optional. It seems different generations have different concepts of what is optional and what is not.
